# Example of two sequences that have opposite relation between their values and limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Is there an example of two sequences $a_n$ , $b_n$ that fulfill the following conditions?

- $a_n$ and  $b_n$ are not constant sequences.
- $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$ $<$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$
- $b_n > a_n$ for each n.

Comment: You should be able to prove quite easily that if $b_n>a_n$ for each $n$, then $\lim_nb_n\ge\lim_na_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $b_n>a_n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\ge\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Equality can occur, as shows the example $a_n=-1/n$, $b_n=1/n$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the last two conditions are incompatible.

I assume that the second condition says implicitly that both sequences converge.

Let be $a=\lim a_n$, $b=\lim b_n$.

Let $\epsilon=(a-b)/2>0$.

Then there exists some $n$ such that $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$ and $|b_n-b|<\epsilon$. Therefore,
$b_n-a_n<(b+\epsilon)-(a-\epsilon)=b-a+2\epsilon=0$. That contradicts the third condiction.